# Disabled DCache will prevent atomic_flag from being set

Tags: c, caching, arm, atomic, zynq

We are using a zynq-7000 based CPU, so an cortex-a9 and we encountered the following issue while using atomic_flags which are inside an library we are using (open-amp).

We are using the second CPU on the SoC to execute bare-metal code.
When disabling the dcache, atomic ints are no longer able to be set, here's a simple code which triggers the issue for us:

```c
#define XREG_CONTROL_DCACHE_BIT (0X00000001U<<2U)
#define XREG_CP15_SYS_CONTROL   "p15, 0, %0,  c1,  c0, 0"
#define mfcp(rn)    ({uint32_t rval = 0U; \
             __asm__ __volatile__(\
               "mrc " rn "\n"\
               : "=r" (rval)\
             );\
             rval;\
             })
#define mtcp(rn, v) __asm__ __volatile__(\
             "mcr " rn "\n"\
             : : "r" (v)\
            );

static void DCacheDisable(void) {
    uint32_t CtrlReg;
    /* clean and invalidate the Data cache */
    CtrlReg = mfcp(XREG_CP15_SYS_CONTROL);

    CtrlReg &= ~(XREG_CONTROL_DCACHE_BIT);
    /* disable the Data cache */
    mtcp(XREG_CP15_SYS_CONTROL, CtrlReg);
}

int main(void) {
    DCacheDisable();

    atomic_int flag = 0;
    printf("Before\n");
    atomic_flag_test_and_set(&flag);
    printf("After\n");
}
```

The CPU executes the following loop for `atomic_flag_test_and_set`:

```
dmb     ish
ldrexb  r1, [r3] ; bne jumps here
strexb  r0, r2, [r3]
cmp     r0, #0
bne     -20     ; addr=0x1f011614: main + 0x00000060
dmb     ish
```

but the register `r0` always stays `1`.
When omitting the function call to `DCacheDisable`, the code works flawlessly.

I really can't find any any information about disabled dcache and atomic flags.

Does anybody has a clue?

Toolchain: We are using vitis 2022.2 which comes with a `arm-xilinx-eabi-gcc.exe (GCC) 11.2.0`. Compiler options are `-O2 -std=c11 -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=hard`

Comment: That makes sense; apparently `strexb` always fails because the L1d cache didn't maintain exclusive ownership of that cache line since the `ldrexb`.  Because caching was disabled.  Apparently the microarchitecture doesn't have an alternative bus-lock method of making LL/SC transactions succeed without cache.  (Interesting, can ARM in general not do atomic RMWs on uncacheable memory regions, like MMIO?)    Perhaps with ARMv8.1 single-instruction RMWs on cores that support it?  Or with the legacy `swp` instruction?

Comment: Why are you using `atomic_flag_test_and_set( atomic_flag * )` on an `atomic_int`?  (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag_test_and_set).  That's strict-aliasing UB and should give a warning if it compiles at all.  Use `atomic_exchange(&flag, 1)` if you want to use `atomic_int` or `atomic_bool`.  The asm is fine, though, so that C weirdness isn't the problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes that sounds like a promising solution. Thanks for that detailed input.
I "just copied" the code that open-amp was using to generate a MCVE. See https://github.com/OpenAMP/open-amp/blob/accac4d3610cbb268f3c3fe3c31dc45dd4c4dd17/apps/machine/zynq7/zynq_a9_rproc.c#L69 and https://github.com/OpenAMP/open-amp/blob/accac4d3610cbb268f3c3fe3c31dc45dd4c4dd17/apps/machine/zynq7/platform_info.h#L50

Comment: I believe I had similar issue a while ago. But that was some 'Rockchip' AArch64 SoC. And changing atomic variable was hanging cpu when cache was disabled. Surprisingly same code worked fine on Zynq7000 (AArch32) and Zynq-Ultrascale (in AArch64 mode).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is common on ARM platforms that support a cache.  The cache line is being used as a temporary store for the exclusive lock.  The term in ARM is [exclusive reserve granule](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dht0008/a/arm-synchronization-primitives/exclusive-accesses/exclusive-monitors) or the size of locked memory.  On systems with a cache, you will find the granule is a cache line size.

So internally, the `ldrex` and `strex` are implemented as part of the cache resolution policy.  You can [compare it to cortex-m systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043489/ldrex-strex-with-cortex-m3-and-m4), where the entire memory space is a reserve granule.

The `ldrex`/`strex` pair are useless for synchronizing with external devices that are not part of an AXI structure.  If you want to disable cache to work with an FPGA interface, I don't believe this can work.  You would need to implement the cache protocol in the FPGA.

For Cortex-M systems, there is no cache structure and custom logic implements a 'global monitor'.

The cache mechanism actually seems useful as the cache line could be used as a transactional memory.  Ie, either the whole line commits on not.  It seems possible to create lock-free algorithm for structures with multiple pointers.  The node do not lock an entire list but only an entry.  However, I haven't seen it used like this ever.  Mainly I think because the ARM documentation recommends not to do this (do not rely on the ERG size).

Comment: The [C++ 'memory model'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319146/c11-introduced-a-standardized-memory-model-what-does-it-mean-and-how-is-it-g) does seem to generate good code with `g++` (and probably clang as well).  Although, it may fail for your use case, (Cortex-A bare metal).  I would recommend it for user of Linux or a Cortex-M system as opposed to custom coding.  The compiler will do data flow analysis, so it is actually much better than an `atomic_flag_test_and_set()` routine.  Unfortunately, the Cortex-A is the most complex beast in this regard.